# Powershell Get-FTPItem 101 argument is greater than maximum allowed range of 100 when downloading

Tags: powershell

I'm having a problem with downloading a file via Powershell Get-FTPItem.
The download starts OK but then throws the following error :
Get-FTPItem : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'PercentComplete'. The 101 argument is greater than the maximum all
owed range of 100. Supply an argument that is less than 100 and then try the command again.

I am using pretty much the same code to download from elsewhere without problems.

Here is my code :

```
    set-executionpolicy RemoteSigned
    Set-Location 'C:\CMD\'
    import-module PSFTP

    # Get date values  
    $Date = Get-Date  
    $FileDate = Get-Date
    [String]$Year = $Date.Year  
    [String]$Month = $Date.Month  
    [String]$Day = $Date.Day
    [String]$Weekday = $date.dayofweek

    if ($Weekday -eq "Monday") {$FileDate = $Date.AddDays(-3)}
    else
    {$FileDate = $Date.AddDays(-1)}

    $FileYear = $FileDate.Year
    $FileMonth = $FileDate.Month
    $FileDay = $FileDate.Day

    # Pad date parts with leading 0's  
    If ( $FileMonth.ToString().Length -lt 2 ) { $FileMonth = '0' + $FileMonth }  
    If ( $FileDay.ToString().Length -lt 2 ) { $FileDay = '0' + $FileDay } 

    #Set file name dates
    $FuturesFile = 'settle\nymex_future.csv'
    $FuturesLocalFile= 'c:\cmd\nymex_future.csv'
    $OptionsFile = 'settle\nymex_option.csv'
    $OptionsLocalFile = 'c:\cmd\nymex_option.csv'

    #Open FTP session and download
    $FTPServer = 'ftp.cmegroup.com'
    $FTPUserName = 'anonymous'
    $FTPPassword = 'Password'
    $FTPSecurePWD = $FTPPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $FTPCredential = New-Object         System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($FTPUsername,$FTPSecurePWD)
    Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FTPCredential -Server $FTPServer -Session MySession -UsePassive
    $Session = Get-FTPConnection -Session MySession
    Get-FTPItem -session $Session -Path $FuturesFile -LocalPath     $FuturesLocalFile -Overwrite
    Get-FTPItem -session $Session -Path $OptionsFile -LocalPath $OptionsLocalFile -Overwrite
```

A zero byte file is generated for the failed file.

Maybe this is something to do with the FTP session ? The variant of this that works requires an authentication, the problem site is anonymous but the connection is established without errors.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `-UseBinary` to your `Set-FTPConnection`

Comment: Thanks that works.